# how to align the text vertically along with the div?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-position

I have created a circular multi-step progress UI with HTML and CSS, here I need to add a text underneath the circular icon, When I have added the text, the line which crosses the bar is moved down. Because the height of the circle is increasing based on the content length. How to make the line always at the center even when we are adding content.

here is the screenshot of it.

**Before adding the content:**

[image]

**After adding the content:**

[image]

I am facing challenges with the CSS. It would be great if u could help me with this issue.

Here is the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ride-fmcild?file=/src/App.js)

**App.js**

```
import CheckIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Check";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const steps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return (
    <>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="progress-container">
          <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
          {steps.map((val) => (
            <div>
              <div className={`circle ${val === 4 ? "active" : ""}`}>
                {val === 4 ? <CheckIcon sx={{ fontSize: "3rem" }} /> : null}
              </div>
              <div className="test">
                {val % 2 === 0
                  ? "Conservative"
                  : "Somewhat Conservative but it is okay"}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**style.css**:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap");

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 700px;
}

.progress-container::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #767676;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress {
  /* background-color: var(--line-border-fill); */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid #767676;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.circle.active {
  border-color: #3769ff;
  background-color: #3769ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.test {
  max-width: 85px;
}
```

**Results**

** `<hr/>` tag length is reduced when minimizing the screen size.**

Demo link is added in the posted answer comment

[image]

Comment: Wanna a simple fast solution? okay set `.test { position: absolute; }`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

hope this is what you aim to  achieve :

this is what i did : i used hr instead of ::before but it doesnt matter,
in your case the before is at the center of `.progress_container`  which height includes the space occupied by the text so instead of putting it at the center of the parent put it at the center of the circles like this `top:calc(circle_height / 2 )`

here are my changes:

```js
import CheckIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Check";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const steps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return (
    <>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="progress-container">
          <hr/>
         
          {steps.map((val) => (
            <div>
              <div className={`circle ${val === 4 ? "active" : ""}`}>
                {val === 4 ? <CheckIcon sx={{ fontSize: "3rem" }} /> : null}
              </div>
              <div className="test">
                {val % 2 === 0
                  ? "Conservative"
                  : "Somewhat Conservative but it is okay"}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

css

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap");

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 700px;
}

hr{
  position:absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 90%;
  background: #000;
  top: calc(85px / 2);
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.progress {
  /* background-color: var(--line-border-fill); */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid #767676;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.circle.active {
  border-color: #3769ff;
  background-color: #3769ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.test {
  max-width: 85px;
}
```

*** effect of the `.container` width on mobile view ***

[image]

Comment: It works, but the hr length is reduced when I reduce the screen size.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-533ffg?file=/src/styles.css:1057-1161

Comment: I have attached the screenshot FYR

Comment: i had put the width to 80% because you are using flex space between if you use 100% it will be shown at end of first and last circle:

Comment: that issue has something to do with the container width on mobile...i have put a screenshot. the circles on mobile are outside the container div. give it a background color `.container` then resize to mobile you see what i mean

Comment: display: inline-flex solves the problem